# MixERP database configuration error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I have cloned the project from github and followed instructions from the MixERP documentation. Built the project in visual studio successfully, installed PostgreSQL version 9.6.

When I ran the project it gave me error

> relation config.mixerp not exist

We are using VS2015, PgAdmin4.

> ERROR: 42P01: relation "config.mixerp" does not exist 
>     Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: Npgsql.NpgsqlException: ERROR: 42P01: relation "config.mixerp" does not exist
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Answer (score 0):

I was running the same version of VS and pgAdmin. I noticed that running the db scripts does not create any tables or views in the database. My suspicion is that mixerp is not completely compatible with PostgreSQL 9.6 as yet. Looking at the DbServer.config, PostgreSQL 9.4 was used during development.

A downgrade of PostgreSQL to v9.4 will resolve the issue you are experiencing. I suggest completely uninstalling PostgreSQL 9.6 and installing PostgreSQL 9.4 instead and thereafter follow the setup document again.